# Cocos2d for iOS. How to determine that the touching has ended?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

If a notification(i.e., a UIAlertView) appears while touching the screen (or home button is being pressed), `ccTouchEnded` will be called in game layer, but at the touch will already have  ended.

How can I determine when the touch ends?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the apple reference for UIResponder:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You probably want

```
touchesEnded:withEvent:
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually I'm using CCTargetedDelegate, and there is no  touchesEnded method

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `ccTouchesCancelled`. This will occur whenever a touch event is interrupted.

Comment: Actually I'm using CCTargetedDelegate, and ccTouchCancelled  never calls

Comment: It's in the protocol: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/_c_c_touch_delegate_protocol_8h_source.html odd that it isn't called

Answer (score 0):

Just check how many touch objects you have.

```
if([touches count] == 0)
{
  //NO TOUCHES
}
```

Comment: I can check it in ccTouchesBegan and ccTouchesEnded. But problem is ccTouchesEnded in some situations not called

Answer (score 0):

-Make your scene conforms to protocol `CCTargetedTouchDelegate`
-Add This line to `init` of your scene:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];
```

-Implement these functions:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
   return  YES;
 }
 -(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
    //here touch is ended
  }
```